# SQL Update using join and conditional aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables on PostgreSQL 11.3:

**sales**:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+
| event_week | store_num | fsaldu | latitude | longitude |
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+
|     201946 |     11249 | K2K3C2 | null     | null      |
|     201947 |     11250 | V6B0G5 | null     | null      |
|     201948 |     11251 | N9H0G6 | null     | null      |
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

**fsa_latlong**:

```
+--------+-------+------+--------------------+-----------+
| fsaldu | fsa5  | fsa4 |      latitude      | longitude |
+--------+-------+------+--------------------+-----------+
| K2K3C2 | K2K32 | K2K3 | 47.006479999999996 |  -52.9587 |
| V6B0G5 | V6B0G | V6B0 | 47.416990000000006 | -53.19438 |
| N9H0G1 | N9H0G | N9H0 | 47.326370000000004 | -52.80969 |
| N9H0G2 | N9H0G | N9H0 | 47.326370000000004 | -52.80969 |
| N9H0G3 | N9H0G | N9H0 | 47.326370000000004 | -52.80969 |
| N9H0G4 | N9H0G | N9H0 | 47.326370000000004 | -52.80969 |
| N9H0G5 | N9H0G | N9H0 | 47.326370000000004 | -52.80969 |
+--------+-------+------+--------------------+-----------+
```

I want to perform a join to update *latitude* and *longitude* in the **sales** table from the **fsa_latlong** table. This was accomplished using this query:

```
update sales s
set latitude = l.latitude,
    longitude = l.longitude
from fsa_latlong l
where s.fsaldu = l.fsaldu;
```

However, some of the *fsaldu* values in the **sales** table do not have a match within the **fsa_latlong** table due to postal codes being retired or reassigned.

So, what I want to accomplish is to take the mean *latitude* and *longitude* from the *fsa5* or *fsa4* level when there isn't an exactly match for the entire postalcode.

My first attempt was this, using a second query after the first join was completed.

```
update sales s
set latitude = (SELECT AVG(l.latitude)
                  FROM fsa_latlong l
                  WHERE s.latitude is null
                  AND (
                      l.fsa5 = substring(s.fsaldu, 1, 5)
                      OR l.fsa4 = substring(s.fsaldu, 1, 4)
                            )),
    longitude = (SELECT AVG(l.longitude)
                  FROM fsa_latlong l
                  WHERE s.longitude is null
                  AND (
                      l.fsa5 = substring(s.fsaldu, 1, 5)
                      OR l.fsa4 = substring(s.fsaldu, 1, 4)
                            ));
```

However, this didn't work as desired. Ideally, I'd like to complete this with a single query, I'm suspecting it uses a `CASE` statement or a `COALESCE` in order to calculate an aggregate when the initial match is null.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add some testdata to your question, such that there exist (partially) matching records.

Comment: Added more relevant test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally,I prefer to do this kind of things in steps. In this case by testing if the previous steps have failed (via the is NULL lat/lon) conditions.

---

```
UPDATE sales s
SET latitude = l.latitude
    ,longitude = l.longitude
FROM fsa_latlong l
WHERE s.fsaldu = l.fsaldu;

UPDATE sales s
SET latitude = agg.latitude
    ,longitude = agg.longitude  
FROM (SELECT l.fsa5
        , AVG(l.latitude) AS latitude
        , AVG(l.longitude) AS longitude
        FROM fsa_latlong l
        GROUP BY l.fsa5
        ) agg
WHERE agg.fsa5 = substring(s.fsaldu, 1, 5)
AND (s.latitude is null OR s.longitude is null)
        ;

UPDATE sales s
SET latitude = agg.latitude
    ,longitude = agg.longitude
FROM (SELECT l.fsa4
        , AVG(l.latitude) AS latitude
        , AVG(l.longitude) AS longitude
        FROM fsa_latlong l
        GROUP BY l.fsa4
        ) agg
WHERE agg.fsa4 = substring(s.fsaldu, 1, 4)
AND (s.latitude is null OR s.longitude is null)
        ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I like this solution and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
WITH
average_values AS (
    SELECT    s.fsaldu,
              AVG(l.latitute)  AS avg_latitude,
              AVG(l.longitude) AS avg_longitude
    FROM      sales s
    LEFT
    JOIN      fsa_latlong   fl
       ON     l.fsa5 = substring(s.fsaldu, 1, 5)
       OR     l.fsa4 = substring(s.fsaldu, 1, 4)
    GROUP BY 1
),
selected_values AS (
    SELECT   av.fsaldu,
             coalesce(fl.laitude,   av.avg_latitude)  AS latitude,
             coalesce(fl.longitude, av.avg_longitude) AS longitue
    FROM     average_values av
    LEFT
    JOIN     fsa_latlong   fl
        ON   wf.fsaldu = fl.fsaldu
)
UPDATE sales s
SET latitude = sv.latitude,
    longitude = sv.longitude
FROM selected_values sv
WHERE s.fsaldu = sv.fsaldu;
```

Notes:

- do you have any good reason to write "I'd like to complete this with a single query,"? it's usually better to have two separate queries than one excessively complicated
- my query is not very efficient, since average is computed for all fsaldu values from sales table. This could be improved easly.

One more general remark - use CTE for subqueries, CTEs are readable and efficient (e.g. you don't have to compute longitude/latitude in separate places).

Comment: Thank you for your response. CTE's definitely seem like the way to go.

Comment: BTW: CTEs *may* be elegant and readable, but in Postgres they act as optimization barriers, and  they are not (yet) efficient. (except when the result set is very small)

Comment: @wildplasser - do you know any example of a query that can't be written using CTEs as efficient as when using subquery? I'd be happy to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that `sales` has a unique id for each row, which I will called `sale_id`:

```
UPDATE sales
    SET latitude = COALESCE(l.latitude, l5.latitude, l4.latitude),
        longitude = COALESCE(l.longitude, l5.longitude, l4.longitude)
FROM sales s LEFT JOIN
     fsa_latlong l
     ON s.fsaldu = l.fsaldu LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT SUBSTR(fsaldu, 1, 5) fsaldu5, AVG(latitude) as latitude, AVG(longitude) as longitude
      FROM fsa_latlong l
      GROUP BY SUBSTR(fsaldu, 1, 5)
     ) l5
     ON l5.fsaldu5 = SUBSTR(s.fsaldu, 1, 5) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT SUBSTR(fsaldu, 1, 4) as fsaldu4, AVG(latitude) as latitude, AVG(longitude) as longitude
      FROM fsa_latlong l
      GROUP BY SUBSTR(fsaldu, 1, 4)
     ) l4
     ON l4.fsaldu4 = SUBSTR(s.fsaldu, 1, 4) 
WHERE s.sales_id = sales.sales_id;
```